# Math Puzzle, finding a sequence with a certain property

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

A certain number of the $5000$ members of the Conway Mathematical Society (each of which has a different membership number between $1$ and $5000$) got together to discuss a puzzle.  Much to their surprise, when they were lining up for lunch they discovered that their membership number formed a sequence of consecutive whole numbers and, moreover, that none of them was standing next to someone whose number was relatively prime to his own.

I have tried a brute force approach to the problem, but I think the problem has only the trivial solution (i.e, only one member).

Comment: Would say, members 21, 222, 324, 252, 627, 282, 930 qualify? e.g. "21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30" What are they particularly asking for?

Comment: I would say so, because if I n is a number, n + 1  would be relatively prime.

Comment: A 42 member sequence: 12,34,56,78,910,1112,1314,...,4748,4950,515,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,960,616,26,36, 4656,66,76,86,970.